# Where is Logger object?

Tags: python

I am trying to test (pytest) some code in python.

I instantiate a logger object with

```
import logging
logging.getLogger()
```

Now I would like to retrieve the logger object created in order to perform some asserts on it.

But if I inspect the global variables I cannot see it.

Where is the Logger object?

---

EDIT: thanks for the responses below 
`logger=logging.GetLooger()`

I am now facing the same problem with `logging.basicConfig()`.

And when I do `r=logging.basicConfig()` , the return value is `None`.
There is still no Logger object in the `globals`

How to find the Logger object in this case?

Comment: Check the return value of `getLogger()`.

Comment: @Jus  thx for your reply. I edited my question to explain more precisely my problem. Can you have a second look?

Comment: what kind of assert you want to do on `logging.basicConfig()`? That method return a None object

Comment: @ennepi this method is supposed to create a Logger object, but I cannot find it. I want to make assert on the logger object

Comment: There is a subtlety to this question, namely that `getLogger` will always return the *same* logger object if called multiple times, so the object is stored *somewhere* whether or not the return value is saved. (Of course, the easiest thing to do is just save the return value.)

Comment: `logging.basicConfig` doesn't create or return a `Logger` instance; it just configures the root logger that already exists. You seem to basically be asking about implementation details of the `logging` module that simply don't matter for using the module.

Comment: Ok yes I found it. I need to first call `basicConfig()` and then `log= GetLogger()` I will then have access to the root logger configured by basicConfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
logging.basicConfig(...)
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

In this way you can to perform asserts on `logger` object configured with the previous `basicConfig` call

Comment: thx for your reply. I edited my question to explain more precisely my problem. Can you have a second look?

Comment: just saw you answered in comment

Answer (score 0):

all logger object store in dictionary format in the current namespace.
you can retrieve all logger object created by using this code.

**from  logging import Logger**

**print(Logger.manager.loggerDict)**

it is a dictionary.

{'**main**': , 'demo.demo.sub_log': , 'demo.demo': , 'demo': }

pls look at key
**main**
demo.demo.sub_log
demo.demo
demo

Hope it will solve your query. it is used as internal working.